# What is this large leaved young tree (US midwest region)?

Tags: identification, trees, plant-care, weeds

What is this plant, and maybe more importantly, how big could it get? I like the large leaves (they're approx 18" wide) but will have to cut it down if it plans to get too large.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be [*Paulownia tomentosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paulownia_tomentosa), the empress tree. It is an ornamental tree that has become an invasive weed tree in many areas. They can grow very fast when young.

They can reach over 80' in height, but more commonly, 30-40 feet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I would definitely agree with the fast growing! I left for a month, came back and it was as big as I am! Unfortunately it'll have to go though. Cheers for sharing.